# Django>=1.7: How to do datamigations like south?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

Django>=1.7 supports schema migrations:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/releases/1.7/#schema-migrations

South supported schema and **data** migrations.

How to create data migrations with Django>=1.7?

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations ?

Comment: Sorry, I was blind. Post it as answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though is not mentioned in release notes, Django>=1.7 support data migration as well. See the dedicated documentation page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: I searched for the south term "freeze". This failed. Now I found all docs I need. Thank you.